# Firebase crashlytics report: what does closure #number mean?

Tags: ios, swift

Firebase crashlytics report: what does closure #number mean?

I saw that Firebase crashlytics reports:

> 已崩溃：com.apple.main-thread
>   EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000104a5be14
>
> 0
>   IOS
>   LoginRegisterInputView.swift - 第 328 行
>   closure #5 in LoginRegisterInputView.initRegisterUI()
>
> 1
>   Then
>   $S4ThenAAPAARlzCrlE4thenyxyxKXEKF + 32
>
> 2
>   IOS
>   LoginRegisterInputView.swift - 第 314 行
>   LoginRegisterInputView.initRegisterUI()
>
> 3
>   IOS
>   LoginRegisterInputView.swift - 第 225 行
>   LoginRegisterInputView.initUI(style:)
>
> 4
>   IOS
>   LoginRegisterInputView.swift - 第 42 行
>   specialized LoginRegisterInputView.init(style:rootVC:)

What is #5 , in this case ?

I think that is the fifth closure in the method `initRegisterUI()`

Here is the related code:

```
func initRegisterUI() {

        self.firstTextfield.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        self.firstTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.secondTextfield.isSecureTextEntry = true
        self.forgetPwButton.removeFromSuperview()
        self.firstTextfield.rx.controlEvent([.editingDidEnd,.editingChanged]).asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: {[weak self] _ in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                strongSelf.clearButton.isHidden = strongSelf.firstTextfield.text!.count < 1
            }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

        let secureButton =  UIButton().then {
            $0.isSelected = false
            $0.setImage(mImage(name: "login_icon_nosee"), for: .normal)
            $0.setImage(mImage(name: "login_icon_see"), for: .selected)
        }
        self.addSubview(secureButton)
        secureButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerY.equalTo((self.secondTextfield)!)
            make.width.equalTo(28)
            make.height.equalTo(24)
            make.right.equalTo(self.clearButton.snp.right)
        }
        secureButton.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext:{ [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            Analysis.shared.push(EVENT_SIGNIN_DISPLAY)
            secureButton.isSelected = !secureButton.isSelected
            strongSelf.secondTextfield.isSecureTextEntry = !secureButton.isSelected
            let text = strongSelf.secondTextfield.text
            strongSelf.secondTextfield.text = nil
            strongSelf.secondTextfield.text = text

        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
        let registerProtocolLabel = UILabel().then {
            let string = "RegisterIterm".localized().replacingOccurrences(of: "<a>", with: "+").replacingOccurrences(of: "</a>", with: "+")
            let array:[String] = string.components(separatedBy: "+")
            $0.font = mThemeMinFont
            if array.count > 0 {
                $0.attributedText = (array[0].color(mRGBA(120, 120, 120, 1)) + array[1].color(mThemePinkColor).underline + array[2].color(mRGBA(120, 120, 120, 1))).attributedText
            }
            $0.textAlignment = .left
            $0.numberOfLines = 0
            $0.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            $0.rx.tapGesture().when(.recognized)
                .subscribe(onNext:{ _ in
                 AppUtils.jumpToWebView(route: AppUtils.getFunctionUrl(.term))
                }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
        }
        let registerProtocolAlertLabel = UILabel().then {
            $0.text = "RegisterItermAlert".localized()
            $0.textColor = mThemePinkColor
            $0.font = mThemeMinFont
            $0.isHidden = true
            $0.textAlignment = .left
            $0.numberOfLines = 0
            $0.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        }
        // ......
```

The related rows:

[image: img code]

The code is of bugs and nasty. It is not written by me, not by my colleague.

Now I am in charge of the bugs.

By checking [the document of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?authuser=0), it is very concise， no details.

Comment: Does it also pertain to line #328 of your class code? Can you provide more of the report?

Comment: Have added, @Glenn

Comment: Ok thanks. So far I have no further idea on this crash issue. Have you tried posting it on RxSwift GitHub issues?

Comment: I will , thanks a lot